# How can I load hr tables to all users in oracle 19c

Tags: sql, oracle19c

How can i copy or load hr tables to all users in loop or there’s another way to do it?

I try copy table and it work but for only one user at a time

Answer (score 1):

Don't. Instead use [Oracle's script to create the `HR` user](https://github.com/oracle-samples/db-sample-schemas/releases/tag/v19.2) and then `GRANT` permissions to each user so that they can `SELECT` from the `HR` schema.

Something like (untested):

```sql
BEGIN
  FOR R IN (
    SELECT at.table_name,
           u.username
    FROM   all_tables at
           CROSS JOIN dba_users u
    WHERE  at.owner='HR'
    AND    u.username != 'HR'
  )
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT SELECT ON HR."'||R.table_name||'" to "'||R.username||'"';
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```